# Table should be only as wide as necessary

Tags: html, width, html-table, autosize

I want a HTML `<table>` to be just the size it needs to be.

Without specifying anything it will span the whole width. Setting `width="auto"` doesn't work.

Comment: check this [link](https://www.google.com.au/#q=set+table+width+css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set width on the table at all. This will make the table only as wide as needed by its content. If this looks too wide, look at the table content to see what causes width requirements in cells. For example, if you have long text in a cell, it will expand the cell to be as wide as needed, within the available width. If you wish to limit this, you need to set `width` or `max-width` on the content of a cell, or the cell itself, or the table.

Comment: I have set the width to nothing and it spans the whole page. There's no wrapped text inside any cell.

Comment: Then you need to post the relevant code (ideally, minimal code that suffices to reproduce the issue, but anyway *some* code, or at least a URL). If you test with `<table border><tr><td>foo</table>`, you can see that it does not span the whole page.

Comment: My bad. There were line wraps all along.

Answer (score 2):

Use `width: fit-content;` for the table. See the difference below:

```css
table, tr, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table#fit-content {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <button>Regular</button>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<br>
<div class='container'>
  <button>With Fit-Content</button>
  <table id='fit-content'>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use CSS style instead of table attributes.

```
table
{
width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Not needed, and does not help; `width: auto` is the default.